# 3D Physics in Marmalade SDK

Tags: physics, marmalade

I am trying to make an 3d  game in Marmalade. I am completely new to Marmalade.

How to add 3d physics, gravity, dynamic object, sensors, colliders in Marmalade.

I was going through the API and did not find anything. Can you guys let me know how to accomplish these things